# next js '_next/static/YzkQBtj6rd9b69Th7lZs0/pages/index.js' error

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have an error in nextjs.

```
www.~~~.com/_next/static/YzkQBtj6rd9b69Th7lZs0/pages/index.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

like this,

I think, I setup nextjs in

> www.~~~.com/beta

but the nextjs call root in

> www.~~~.com

how can I change root or how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was solved this problem.

with apache httpd.conf modify.

modify file: /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

I added this two blocks.

1.

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
ProxyPass /beta http://localhost:3000
```

2.

```
<Location /beta>
  ProxyPass http://localhost:3000
  ProxyPassReverse https://www.~~~.com/beta/
</Location>
```